# jQuery add plus minus button for range for change div width

Tags: jquery, css, html, function, range

Hello I want to create plus minus button for change a range value this my HTML:

```
<label for="points">Width:</label>

<input type="range" name="amountRange" id="points" value="100" min="10" max="100" step="1" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
<input type="text" name="amountInput" id="textnumber" min="10" max="100" step="1" value="100" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" /><span>%</span>
<input type="button" id="plus" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="minus" value="-" />
```

I've tried

```
var counter = document.getElementById("points").value;
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#minus').click(function () {
            counter++;
        });
        $('#points').change(function () {
            $('#navi').css({
                width: this.value + '%'
            });
        });
```

Comment: So what's the problem..?

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted

Comment: var counter  = document.getElementById("points").value;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#minus').click(function() {
                counter --;
            });
        $('#points').change(function () {
            $('#navi').css({ width: this.value + '%' });

        });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with everything working:

http://jsfiddle.net/kgLsky8s/2/

```
var counter = document.getElementById("points").value;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#plus").click(function(){

        var newValuePlus = parseInt($("#textnumber").val()) + 1;
        if ( newValuePlus > 100 ) return;

        $("#points, #textnumber").val(newValuePlus);

    });


    $("#minus").click(function(){

        var newValueMinus = parseInt($("#textnumber").val()) - 1;
        if ( newValueMinus < 0 ) return;

        $("#points, #textnumber").val(newValueMinus);
    }); 

    $("#points").change(function(){

        var newValue = $(this).val();
        $("#textnumber").val(newValue);

    }); 

    $("#textnumber").change(function(){

        var newValue = $(this).val();
        $("#points").val(newValue);

    }); 

});
```

Comment: just one last quetion where i need to add the code of my div to change him with counter this is a code  $('#navi').css({ width: this.value + '%' });

Comment: In every-single block: just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kgLsky8s/4/

Comment: Hello Monte i truing get to the width present % . in this line of code in the end i added a present but the range dont work when i added the present you can help me     var newValuePlus = parseInt($("#textnumber").val() + '%') + 1 + '%';

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kgLsky8s/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery's `.attr()` function... like so:

```
$("#plus").click(function(){

    $("#points, #textnumber").attr("value", parseInt($("#points").attr("value")) + 1); 

});


$("#minus").click(function(){

    $("#points, #textnumber").attr("value", parseInt($("#points").attr("value")) - 1); 

});
```

Comment: ok its great and if iwant to change the width ?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I was just playing with that in a JSFiddle -- give me a minute...

Comment: This actually gets pretty complicated --- Monte's answer is going to be the best. Since you're giving your user three options for inputing the same value (range, text, buttons) - then each input needs to update the others --

Answer (score 1):

A good option would be to use jQuery UI's spinner widget. Remember to import jQuery first, then jQuery UI. Make sure you import the CSS link for jQuery UI too. Then use this javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( "#spinner" ).spinner();
});
```

Additionally, set the ID for the element that you want to be transformed into the spinner widget (preferebly an input) like this:

```
<input id="spinner" type="text">
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but i do not understud what you trying to explain me :)